# Text area not reading HTML

Tags: python, html, django, anaconda

I have Django´s Blog APP installed, all working fine, but I need to add posts (via admin) with HTML in the post content field, now, the text area can only read plain text (it doesn´t render HTML).

This is the field:
(models.py)

```
content = models.TextField()
```

This is the HTML for this field:

```
<h6 class="card-text" ><small>{{post.content|slice:":500" |linebreaks |safe}}</small></h6>
```

Question is: are there special configs for Django/Python in order for the field to render HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `safe` tag should already do that... have you tried this:

```
{% autoescape off %}
    {{ post.content }}
{% endautoescape %}
```

https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/AutoEscaping

Hope this helps!